# How to build loss-free inverter?

Tags: transistors, switches, inverter

I would like to create an inverter because I would like to have an inverse switch, that is: my circuit should only work when some signal current does NOT flow. This is even mechanic: When a certain switch is NOT set, I want no current to flow at all.

The only idea that I have right now is using an NPN transistor in parallel with my circuit, while the circuit has a higher resistance than the collector-emitter part of the transistor. I could then connect the switch to the base of the transistor. If closed, the main current flows through the emitter-collector. But the down sides clearly are that:

1) current flows, nonetheless

2) a certain current will flow, according to the resistance, through my circuit anyways

My circuit is battery-powered and I would like to not have the battery be consumed at all. I have a 3V coin cell and, without use, it should last weeks or months.

I do not need an electronic inverter, it could also be mechanically triggered (my application is that I have a box and I want to have LEDs glow when it is opened... when the box is closed, I can have contacts closed, i.e., a closed switch; but I cannot close a switch when the box is opened)

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: I don't quite understand what about your application the switch itself wouldn't solve?

Comment: @MarcusMüller How should I mechanically design a switch that is closed when I open the box, I don't see that. I can only design a box that closes a switch, when I close the box. But then, the LEDs would glow when the box is closed. I want the LEDs to glow when the box is opened.

Comment: but switches come in both, normally closed and normally open configuration? I really don't see the problem.

Comment: ... exactly the kind of switch that closes when you open your fridge door.

Comment: @MarcusMüller well, I would need to build that myself. At the moment, I close contacts with aluminium foil. Is there some way to build a push-to-break switch myself?

Comment: You can make your own push-to-break switch. Think "car door light switch".

Comment: Mind-boggling that is. I find it mind-boggling how something which is obviously obvious for an EE is obviously in no way obvious for a NEE.

Comment: @Ariser I guess. What exactly do you mean, though? This whole thing seemed like an easy problem but it was not that easy after all, as I need a special part.

Comment: @SteveG I seem to be searching totally wrongly, how do you find DIY instructions using this term? I have entered it with DIY and "do it yourself" and "how to build" and so on, and so on... they only show how to exchange those things in existing garages

Comment: @IceFire A switch, which opens a circuit when pressed is as normal as the type which closes at the same event. Both variants are so commonly needed that a lot of MF decided to produce only combined NC/NO devices (SPDT in English). It is such a common pronciple that I don't even remember when I learned about it. That's what I'm wondering about.

Comment: @Ariser I see! Well, I had no switch at all to begin with. I merely created a mechanism because my box had two small areas that would touch when closed, so that I put aluminium foils to them to have a nice switch. When using this procedure, inverting the switch is not as trivial. Since time is an issue and no shop was close by, I wanted to work with I had. But this does not seem to be possible. I have now acquired a nice NC switch and hope that my box can press it easily

Comment: @IceFire Ah, I see! ok, you should have described your current NO-solution in more detail. (add it to your question) This, of course cannot be inverted that easily.

Comment: @Ariser yeah, I was simultaneously interested in the "professional" solution and in the "amateur solution with no materials" which converted in this poorly written question. You helped me in both ways, though, so thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to buy a NC-switch. There are a lot of these devices.

If you don't want to change the type of the switch (I'm assuming you have some sort of NO-switch), you can flip the switch around, add a spring which keeps the NO-switch in the closed position and add some sort of a lever which acts against the spring. The lever then can be moved by closing the box.

*Edit*

After having understood OP's self made switch's principle, I feel urged to deliver another self made NC-solution.

Fix a clothes-peg inside the box with its mouth facing towards the box' cover. Do it by e.g. glueing or screwing one lever to the wall of the box. Put tin foil onto the other lever and contact it with another tin-foil wrapped plastic or wood piece glued to the bottom of the box. Then apply a nail to the box cover so that it opposes the clothes-peg's mouth. When the cover is put in place the nail should pry the mouth of the peg open lifting the moving lever away from the foil wrapped piece. That's your NC-switch.

Comment: any recommendation for a NC switch or a synonym? I'm searching for "push to break" switch or "nc switch" in some shops and do not find anything

Comment: https://produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/1400000-1499999/001493541-da-01-en-U_MINIATUR_SCHALTER_STOESSEL_IP67_NASE_R.pdf there are versions of this switch at conrad with NC. But you can always use any switch with both contacts and ignore the NO contact: https://www.conrad.de/de/search.html?search=mikroschalter&sort=Price-asc&tfo_ATT_LOV_CONTACT-TYPE=1%20Wechsler

Comment: @IceFire you might be looking in the wrong shops. My local Baumarkt (construction material shop) has such switches for the purpose of turning on lights when one opens a door. I also can't believe [this 150 000 switch](https://www.mouser.de/Electromechanical/Switches/_/N-5g2hZscv7) collection doesn't have what you're looking for.

Comment: @Ariser ah, nice, thank you! What gives away that this is normally turned on? Is it only because of the "on/(off)" label? How did you find this one?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yeah... question is: *how* do I find push-to-break switches? What is the search term for them? (I am German, too, and cannot find a translation, either)

Comment: it's "Normally closed", or "NC" in the search field, typically

Comment: "Öffner" is a good selection term on a German electronics distributor webshop. If you can waste a pin (rofl) use "Wechsler". works as well and brings a lot more results.

Comment: @MarcusMüller nothing at reichelt or Conrad even if you switch to English, but both are too much German, probably

Comment: @IceFire I gave you words for english websites and you used them on German websites. I assure you there's enough Öffner, Wechselschalter etc switches on Reichelt.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I used them on English reichelt because the product names are also switched to English, but they seem to translate not so well. My bad! "Öffner" is nice, though, you just have to limit search results a lot further. Thank you!

Comment: @Ariser suggested Öffner an hour ago, but I think he sees your "thank you" and is happy he/she helped.

Comment: @Ariser thank you, too, "Öffner" seems to work fine

Answer (score 5):

> I have a box and I want to have LEDs glow when it is opened

I can think of several options...

- A switch designed to light the inside of a cupboard when the door is opened. Available at home improvement stores, online, etc. Keywords: Door light switch. Caveat: make sure the switch closes when the door opens!

[image]

- Magnetic switches for alarm systems. Beware: these will usually be closed when the door is closed, you want the opposite. The one on the picture below has both options:

[image]

- A microswitch, possibly with a lever. Get a 3 pin one, so it has NO and NC contacts. Cheap and readily available, but it will make a "click" sound.

[image]

- Reed switch and magnet. Easy to find and silent.

[image]

I can't remember whether the "Normally" in "NO" means "there is a magnet nearby" or not, so I'd just pick a 3 wire switch...

[image]

- DIY option

[image]

You can buy these leaf switches, but you can also DIY. When the door presses on the plastic knob on the right of the picture, the two contacts separate and the circuit is opened. When the door is opened, the springy contacts come back together and the circuit is closed.

Comment: Very nice summary of options (and words for the particular switches), thank you very much!